# Can a MovieClip show it's guide layer on main timeline?

Tags: flash, adobe

I'm working with a MovieClip object that is invisible (blank) on it's first frame, so it is also invisible on the main timeline. To deal with this I've put an extra layer called "Delete this" with a reference image on the first frame.

It seems to me that this is exactly what a Guide layer should be for, but guide layers for an object don't appear on the main timeline. Is there a way to make objects display their guide layers on parent timelines during development?

Note: since I'll be reusing this object a lot in the future I'll eventually write some code to skip the first frame (and I know how to do this). But I would genuinely like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: On your **timeline** toolbar you can set layer name, right? Then next to that is the "eye" for toggle layer visibility, next to that is padlock for lock/unlock layer and finally next to that is "view layer as outline" which is what you want. Whichever layer has your MC just set to "view outline" mode and you'll see outline of the MC area. Click the colour box of that layer to set a different outlines colour.

Comment: @VC.One That doesn't work because the first frame of the MC is blank.

Comment: Instead of a reference image just draw a rectangle and set "0%" alpha next to colour. Anyways... why have a blank frame? Better to delete that frame so 2nd frame is the new first frame. If you want something not visible until ready just use `myMC.visible = false`. You'll see it on stage whilst editing but when running the app it'll be invisible, then instead of `myMC gotoAndStop(2);` to show content you use `myMC.visible = true;` etc

Comment: Thanks @VC.One.
So the answer to my original question would be "No, you cannot show the guide layer of a MC on the main timeline" then?

Comment: No you cannot show anything of any empty frame. The nearest is to use "onion skin" option but that only works inside the MC itself to show outlines of its own timeline's later frame(s). You're not even supposed to have an empty frame anyway, what's the logic to that?

Comment: Well the "logic" is that I have a very nice animation of the object appearing from nothing. But I've implemented your idea so I can see the bounding box clearly now. Thanks